# SAS EG Use grid if able

Tags: sas

I am a SAS newbie and use EG because i'm not a SAS programmer.  There are options in query properties under Code Submission that says 'Use grid if able' and 'Allow parallel processing on same server'.

I have to pull data from large datasets and would love to speed things up on the grid but every time I check these boxes, I get an error.  Can someone tell me what I can do to set this up?

Thanks
Jeff

Comment: can you share the ERROR you receive?

Comment: Do you have a SAS Grid setup? This would mean you have a cluster of SAS worker nodes. Otherwise, this option won't do much for you. You can do parallel processing on the same server assuming you have the right software installed, but it is only usable in certain situations.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I didn't know that there's stuff behind the scenes that needs to happen too.  i'll have to ask about the grid...I know we can connect to the grid in code but I don't have the proficiency for that.  I tried it (and asked a question here about it too) but it is a little over my head.